# How do I run software as an administrator using Wine/PlayonLinux?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Today I was wondering if I could run a Program I installed on a virtual drive as an administrator?

I installed Cain and Abel on this drive, When I run the program it works fine. But in order for it to actually work, you need to run as admin.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?